# How should i code a column layout?

Tags: views, blocks, panels

I'm new to Drupal and I thought a lot about planing a column layout at my frontpage. In each column there is a teaser list of nodes. I have one row with 3 columns, the next with 2 columns... I can't upload the mockup, but I hope you imagine what I'm working on. The important thing is grouping the node lists to different columns.

So what should i use to code this? Blocks? Views? Something with panels? At the moment I'm a little bit confused about all these options...

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the brevity of your description, it is hard to say exactly. If you want to avoid custom coding and use contrib code (always a good thing to try first, in my option), I would consider the following.

- Views Page
- manager
- List item

Panels.

There is a good tutorial on the above (free at the moment) from the good people at Lullabot. The presentation is actually done by Node One, and is one of the best I've seen.

http://drupalize.me/series/learning-page-manager

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I made it with a Panel and the Page Manager!